# expanding type equation generator in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, typechecking

```
type exp = 
  | CONST of int
  | VAR of var
  | ADD of exp * exp
  | SUB of exp * exp
  | ISZERO of exp
  | IF of exp * exp * exp
  | LET of var * exp * exp
  | PROC of var * exp
  | CALL of exp * exp
and var = string

type typ = TyInt | TyBool | TyFun of typ * typ | TyVar of tyvar
and tyvar = string

type typ_eqn = (typ * typ) list

module TEnv = struct
  type t = var -> typ
  let empty = fun _ -> raise (Failure "Type Env is empty")
  let extend (x,t) tenv = fun y -> if x = y then t else (tenv y)
  let find tenv x = tenv x
end

let rec gen_equations : TEnv.t -> exp -> typ -> typ_eqn 
=fun tenv e ty -> match e with
| CONST n -> [(ty, TyInt)]
| VAR x -> [(ty, TEnv.find tenv x)]
| ADD (e1,e2) -> [(ty, TyInt)]@
    [gen_equations (tenv, e1, TyInt)]@
    [gen_equations (tenv, e2, TyInt)]
```

[Implementing type equation generator in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932737/implementing-type-equation-generator-in-ocaml#)

I'm expanding type checker based on above code

What I want to do is add "EQUAL" expression, which take two input and return TyBool as output

Problem is how to make equation of input, as input is not a fixed type.

EQUAL can take both TyInt and TyBool as input

ex)

EQUAL (FALSE, FALSE) have output TRUE (because false == false)

EQUAL (5, 3) have output FALSE (because 5 != 3)

How can I make equation?

Answer (score 0):

Your `EQUAL` expression has a polymorphic type, i.e., it is typable for integers and variables. It is your choice, as a language designer, which flavor of polymorphism you will implement. You can start with the classical [parametric polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)). In that case, you will type `EQUAL` as `'a -> 'a -> bool`, or, in the parlance of your representation,

```
TyFun (TyVar a, TyFun (TyVar a, TyBool))
```

Then, during the unification process, the type variable `a` will be unified either with TyBool or with TyVar (well, it could also unify with functional types, which you can turn into a type error if you wish).

Alternatively, you can implement `EQUAL` using [ad-hoc polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism). This will require you to change your type system though, i.e., to add new constructors to your type `typ`. You can take the type classes approach and have `TyCls of string * typ` and give `EQUAL` the following type,

```
TyFun (TyCls ("comparable",t), TyFun (TyCls ("comparable",t), TyBool))
```

But inference with type classes is hard and is not always decidable.